# How to make this Javascript incasesensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a website with a text input box.

I have this piece of code in a JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filterTextBox").on("keyup", function () {
        var search = this.value;
        $(".person").show().filter(function () {
            return $(".name", this).text().indexOf(search) < 0;
        }).hide();        
    });
});
```

With this when I search "hello", it won't find the name "Hello"
Can I make it doesn't matter if it is "Hello" or "hELLo" or whatever?

Comment: so toLowerCase() the string....

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work, I might have done something wrong maybe?

Comment: make sure you `toLowerCase()` both values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You Can

Use `toLowerCase()` to convert all of user inputs to lower case so every time you compare or use a word you already matching the same value if non-casing words

## For Example

```
"Hello".toLowerCase() outputs 'hello'
"hELLo".toLowerCase() outputs 'hello'
```

## In your code

Make sure `$(".name", this).text()` is lowercased before you search for the index of the search value

 **So you code will be something like that**

```
//hide all the elements except for the matches
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filterTextBox").on("keyup", function () {
    var search = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $(".person").show().filter(function () {
        return $('.name', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search)<0;
    }).hide();
  });
});
```

Thanks @mark.hch for your code https://jsfiddle.net/yd9k12bz/

Comment: This worked out on the case sensitive part, but it hides the thing I search for instead of showing it

Comment: @CodeLover best way to deal with this. `Hide` all first and then `Show` where the filter matches each time.

Comment: Yea, I think they assumed it was `hide()` then `filter()` then `show()` instead of show first. Personally, I think either is fine, https://jsfiddle.net/yd9k12bz/

Comment: i updated my answer with @mark.hch answer 
thanks mark for the fiddlelink

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla version shows how everything fits together.

```js
const getPeople = () => document.querySelectorAll('.person');

document.addEventListener('keyup', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('#search')) {
    const searchFor = target.value.toLowerCase();
    if (searchFor.length > 0) {
      getPeople().forEach(p => {
          if (p.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(searchFor)) {
            p.classList.remove('hide');
          } else {
            p.classList.add('hide')
          }
          });
    } else {
      // Show all
      getPeople().forEach(p => p.classList.remove('hide'));
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">Paul T</div>
<div class="person">John B</div>
<div class="person">David C</div>
<div class="person">Lisa A</div>
<div class="person">Claire W</div>
<div class="person">Paul W</div>
<div class="person">John F</div>
<div class="person">David S</div>
<div class="person">Lisa R</div>
<div class="person">Claire B</div>
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Comment: This looks also a great method to do it, but when I run the code snippet from stack overflow, when I type in a name it shows up twice.

Comment: I added the names twice deliberately to show lol, changed it so that is a little more clear.

Comment: I honestly just saw each one once, my fault, thanks anyways!